# Firebase - get firestore Array Data to StreamBuilder Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

```
  child: StreamBuilder(
    stream: databaseReference
      .collection(collectionName)
      .snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      } else {
        return ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: elementList(snapshot),
        );
      }
    }
  ),
```

this is the my StreamBuilder code,

```
  elementList(AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    return snapshot.data.documents.map((document).mydata {
      return ListTile()
    }).toList();
  }
```

**mydata** is the document name like Country, and name of array List,

this is the ListTile building code, and I want get the Country list in this StreamBuilder, and elements to ListTile.
the database looks like,
[FireStore database Country List in the document in the collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uT5g.jpg)

Comment: use a collection in this document and it read in streambuilder, thank you.